# Calling C++ function from Fortran in Visual Studio 2010 with 2003 ISO C binding

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have to call a C++ function from my fortran program. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I read the relevant chapter on 2003 ISO C binding in this book [http://www.amazon.com/Guide-Fortran-Programming-Walter-Brainerd/dp/1848825420](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848825420) . I tried to compile and run the simple example at pag 219 (I copied it below) but it says "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _c referenced in function _MAIN__ ". These are the steps I have followed.

1)I created a Fortran project with the Fortran main program and module and I set it as "startup project".

2)I created a C++ project of type "static library".

3)I added $(IFORT_COMPILERvv)\compiler\lib\ia32 as explained here http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-visual-studio-for-mixed-language-applications

When I compile I get that error. If I comment the Call C line it perfectly runs so it just cannot find the C function. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance. Here are the C and Fortran codes:

```
    module type_def
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       private

       type, public, bind(c) :: t_type
          integer(kind=c_int) :: count
          real(kind=c_float) :: data
       end type t_type
    end module type_def

    program fortran_calls_c
       use type_def
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none

       type(t_type) :: t
       real(kind=c_float) :: x, y
       integer(kind=c_int), dimension(0:1, 0:2) :: a

       interface
          subroutine c(tp, arr, a, b, m) bind(c)
             import :: c_float, c_int, c_char, t_type
             type(t_type) :: tp
             integer(kind=c_int), dimension(0:1, 0:2) :: arr
             real(kind=c_float) :: a, b
             character(kind=c_char), dimension(*) :: m
          end subroutine c
       end interface

       t = t_type(count=99, data=9.9)
       x = 1.1
       a = reshape([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], shape(a))
       call c(t, a, x, y, "doubling x" // c_null_char)
       print *, x, y
       print *, t
       print *, a

    end program fortran_calls_c

    #include "stdafx.h"
    //#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    typedef struct {int amount; float value;} newtype;
    void c(newtype *nt, int arr[3][2], float *a, float *b, char msg[])
    {
        printf (" %d %f\n", nt->amount, nt->value);
        printf (" %d %d %d\n", arr[0][1], arr[1][0], arr[1][1]);
        printf (" %s\n", msg);
        *b = 2*(*a);
    }
```

Comment: Your `c++` function name is going to be mangled. To stop this use [`extern "c"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but I tried to replace the line in the C++ code with extern "C" void c(....) but nothing changed...

Comment: Ok, no one who actually knows what they're doing is chiming in here... I had a play with this once a while ago, and never on Windows, but oh well. Now I had a vague memory that the compiler will stick an _ on the end of function names in Fortran. However in this case the error is `unresolved external symbol _c` so it looks like in Windows it goes on the front. Try `extern "c" void _c (newtype *nt, int arr[3][2], float *a, float *b, char msg[]){...}`.

Comment: Argh I don't get Windows at all. I'd like to suggest switching to a real operating system, but somehow I suspect that isn't a useful answer. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows). Are you compiling the c++ 64 bit?

Comment: Guys, If I have well understood the 2003 C binding already solves all the mangled-name problems. Otherwise why would we use it? In fact the answer below works but it is wierd you have to do that and for each C++ project you add.

Comment: @Alberto BIND(C) relates to Fortran to C interoperability, not C++.

Comment: No IanH on that book it only mentions bind(C), it should work with both C and C++. See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825843/passing-a-fortran-int-array-to-c-by-calling-c-function-in-fortran

Comment: @Alberto Perhaps I've misunderstood what you think is weird.  If you are referring to the need for extern "C" in the C++ code - that's  because you need to tell the C++ compiler to make the name "C compatible" (give the function C linkage), otherwise the default linkage is C++.  It is "C compatible" stuff that BIND(C) on the Fortran side interoperates with.  If you are referring to the need to explicitly designate the location of the library in VS, that's just a consequence of the project build systems for C++ and Fortran being different in VS2010.

Comment: For the OP - note that the "Intel configuring VS for mixed language article" that you refer to applies when your main program is not Fortran.  Your main program is Fortran - the specification of the location of the Fortran runtime libraries to the linker is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Answer now edited to reflect advice and knowledge in comment from IanH:

As @BoBTFish suggested, plonk `extern "C"` onto the declaration of the C++ function `c`.  Make sure, of course, that you use a capital C, some of the commentary has been a bit loose there.

I commented out the source line which includes `stdafx.h` which seems to be optional anyway and I couldn't be bothered looking for or creating it.

After that set, for the Fortran project,

- the Linker / General / Additional Library Directories to the directory where the `lib` file is; and
- Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies to specify the `lib` file.

Set the runtime library options for the C++ and Fortran projects to be the same.  In the Fortran project's properties pages set Fortran / Libraries to `Debug Multithread DLL`.

Now it compiles and executes and produces the following:

```
 99 9.900000
 2 3 4
 doubling x
   1.100000       2.200000
          99   9.900000
           1           2           3           4           5           6
```

Thanks to IanH's input I'm now a better informed script-following monkey.

Comment: Thanks it works. But could somebody elaborate on this? Is it safe to ignore MSVCRTD.lib. Why this errors related to MSVCRTD.lib? I still have some worning though that are:                                                
  1>ipo: warning #11073: provaC.lib(prova.obj): locally defined symbol __imp__printf imported
1>provaC.lib(prova.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
1>provaC.lib(prova.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _printf imported in function _c

Comment: And also the warning:  1>warning LNK4204: '..\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info

Comment: The warning about MSVCRTD.lib is likely to be because you have two different instances of the C runtime library (one DLL based, one static) being linked into the same executable.  Rather than the "ignore specific library", set the runtime library option for the C++ and Fortran project to be the same - perhaps change the Fortran setting under Fortran > Libraries > Runtime library to [Debug] Multithread DLL.

Comment: Yep thanks I chose now a Static Multithread and it does not produce any error or warning ( I clearly do not ignore anymore MSVCRTD.lib).

Comment: I am driving crazy...this worked for this example...then when I tried to link my personal fortran project with another C++ project it kept doing the errors even using Debug Multithreaded (/libs:static /threads /dbglibs). I solved changing in C++property -> configurations ->general -> use of MFC ->Use MFC in a Static Library . It s weird cause the example above was working just with "Use Standard Windows Libraries"

Comment: Again, confirm you have consistent runtime library settings.  In the C++ project you will find the relevant project property under C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library.  If you have further issues specific to this compiler it may be worthwhile asking at the [Intel forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/) - this sort of question comes up regularly there, plus you can attach build logs, project configuration files, etc to your post that give a complete picture to readers as to what your settings are.